# Using Pydoc documentation module for whole project in Pycharm

Tags: python, pydoc

I know, that there are some cases with pydoc module, but none of them were helpful for me.

First of all, structure of my project is following:

Model_folder

```
folder_1
    subfolder_1
        python_file_1
        python_file_2
    subfolder_2
folder_2
    subfolder_1
        python_file_1
        ...
        python_file_10
    subfolder_2
    subfolder_3
folder_3
...
folder_4
...
```

I create a simple batch file to run pydoc module in every folder in Model_Folder as following:

```
for /r PATH %%a in (.) do (  
    pushd %%a  
    set PYTHONPATH =.
    python -m pydoc -w .\  
    popd
)
```

The batch file is working, but I get an error, when it tries to evaluate one of the module:

*problem in folder_1.subfolder_1.python_file_1.html - No module named folder_2*

It is problem, to do pydoc documentation for module, in which we import something from other modules? Because I am importing some function from folder_2 in python_file_1 in folder_1.

Comment: based on you structure there is no python-file in `folder_2`, just in its subfolders ...

Comment: can you provide any more details: like the import statement from `folder_1.subfolder_1.python_file_1.html` - and why you have python imports in html?

Comment: to be more precise, I want to import from 'folder2.subfolder_1.python_file_1' in 'folder_1.subfolder_1.python_file_1' but it shows me only error above, that No module names folder_2.

I need to have there import because I am using some function from 'folder_2.subfolder_1.python_file_1' because in our project we declare some function in one place and use them in another place.

Comment: well I guess then pydocs don't find any parent folders - since you are changing the directory to a subfolder. May try without setting PYTHONPATH .?

Comment: I was trying it also without setting PYTHONPATH, but without any change the error was the same. I put it htere, because I read somewhere that it could help.

Answer (score -1):

I assume those folders are package/module/submodule hierarchy. If so, you need to run pydoc from the package/module folder, not from the submodule's folder.

So my untested modification is

```
    for /r PATH %%a in (.) do (  
        python -m pydoc -w .\  
    )
```

In all of [Github I couldn't find anyone attempting to do this in batch](https://github.com/search?l=Batchfile&p=1&q=%22pydoc%20-w%22&type=Code).

Here is folder-walking example [using python](https://github.com/andreww5au/PaSD-client/blob/4ea5fac6cb6b00e3aabad09a2974e0fd9b2ef949/gendocs.py).